# Did Dovid hamelech write music?

Tags: history, music, king-david

Do we have any music notes or tunes attributed to him?

On the same note, do we have any music or songs attributed to biblical times? If not, why is that?

EDIT: do we know any tunes or songs even without notation?

Comment: I don't think that notation (Hah!) was invented then.

Comment: What about songs or tunes? Either from Dovid Hamelech or from the Levi'im singing in the beis hamikdosh?

Comment: I'm surmising that, in fact, David did write music. If we assume that Tehillim were written by David, we see numerous Tehillim that start with words like "For the Gittit" - "For the Shminit" - both musical instruments (different types of harps.) Likewise, many Tehillim start with "Lamentzeach" - for the choir-master. I'm unaware that anyone else wrote any Tehillim except for David. As for musical notes - well that's what the trope is all about. I don't know how to sing Tehillim trope, but, IIRC correctly, Yemenite version does know how to sing this. I guess you could consider that the tune.

Comment: @DanF I have heard that not all the tehillim was composed by Dovid. Sons of Korach, tefilla limoshe...

Comment: @larry909 That may be true. It wouldn't detract from the strong possibility that David wrote music. We know that he played the harp, esp. in front of King Sha'ul. It's probably likely that he composed all the songs he played for him. Unless the only thing he played constantly was *Shirat Hayam*.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It wasn't??? What about trope - aka *ta'amei hamikra*?

Comment: @larry909 - http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2981847/jewish/Who-Wrote-the-Book-of-Psalms.htm

Comment: @DanF Is the trope from Biblical times? (as an aside, I think it is, I vaguely recall some Medrash or something saying that the tunes were given at Har Sinai as well. But then again, that's what the question is asking, so if you have a source, there's the answer!)

Comment: @Salmononius2 I believe that trope is part of the Mesorah. That's one part of my research. The 2nd aspect is that even if it was, was it meant for music as well as grammar?

Comment: @DanF Trop is a melody, which was an Oral Mesorah (You have to read the Torah in a certain way). Regular melodies weren't nearly as important.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I pretty much understand that the Torah was given together with the trope. As for the other books of Tanac"h, I'm not certain if the trope was included with it at the same time that the books were written. Would you have any info on that?

Comment: @DanF The point is that Trop isn't your classical "notation" - You can't write arbitrary melodies with Trop. And it was an Oral Mesorah (so no notation) until it was written down about a thousand years ago.

Comment: Larry - I'm not sure how much you have been following the more recent comments. I think your question is somewhat vague. There were numerous Biblical songs, as you prob. know starting with The Song of the Sea, perhaps, the earliest noted Biblical song. I think it's understoofd that much of Tehillim was written by King David, and many of them were composed as musical songs. It probably was sung by the Masoretic trope, but, I don't think anyone would know for certain. Regardless, the current "western" musical notation was invented far later than any of this. Perhaps spec. type of music in the Q?

Comment: @DanF added an edit

Comment: @DanF those biblical songs you mention. does anyone know the tune

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The Zohar "darshins" the shape of the Zarka note (on אבינו מת במדבר), so either [that part of] the Zohar is from only a thousand years ago, or it was written down well before then. (As it happens the shape of the Zarka note has changed over the centuries as seen in Chumashim, and the shape the Zohar refers to is most similar to the one popular in 13th century spain.)

Comment: @DanF I am very doubtful that the trope notation existed in biblical times. Do you have any evidence that it existed before the Masoretes?

Comment: @Daniel It did exist, but most likely was not written in the form that we have it now. That fact, however, would not detract from the concept that David might have placed the trope there already, and that all of his Tehillim were sung using the trope. If that's true, than what we have now is the original version of his songs.

Comment: Josephus ([Antiq., Book 7, ch. 12:3](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2848/2848-h/2848-h.htm#link72HCH0012)) writes: "And now David being freed from wars... composed songs and hymns to God of several sorts of metre; some of those which he made were trimeters, and some were pentameters. He also made instruments of music, and taught the Levites to sing hymns to God, both on that called the sabbath day, and on other festivals."

Comment: @DanF good point. (but we don't know the tunes... )

Comment: @Daniel I would venture that the Torah was sung to some tune. At least something like Shirat Hayam was probably sung. So, I think the "notes" must have been around but the Masorrites were the first to write them.